# type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to show data from firebase and am getting this error code.

Here is where:

```
              Text(
                ['Rating'].toString() ?? "empty"),
              Text(
                ['Name'] ?? "empty"),
              Text(
                ['Location'] ?? "empty)
```

...

```
 return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                buildContactCard(context, snapshot.data.docs[index]));
```

Comment: The error is actually sufficiently descriptive. `Text` widget accepts `String` as its first positional argument and you're using `['Name']` which is `List<String>`. However the entire line `['Name'] ?? "empty"` makes no sense as `??` is operator which returns rvalue in case lvalue is `null` which, as you're using it, will never happen. Perhaps you could explain to us what you were trying to achieve with `['Name'] ?? "empty"` and we can assist you further?

Comment: Hi @nstosic, here is why I added ?? "empty" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343386/a-non-null-string-must-be-provided-to-a-text-widget-flutter.     

I am trying to display the firebase data on the Card widget

Comment: You probably meant to use `someDataObject['Name']` instead of just `['Name']`.

Comment: You should really read the [dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @Nitrodon. An approved answer would be nice for the next visitors to this page. The `Text()` widget requires a string variable, not a list. Assuming that you have a contact snapshot, it should look like this:

```
          Text(
            contact.data()['Rating'].toString() ?? "empty"),
          Text(
            contact.data()['Name'] ?? "empty"),
          Text(
            contact.data()['Location'] ?? "empty")
```